# PayPal API how set what will appear on credit card or bank statement

Tags: api, paypal, payment

The question is about PayPal API create button: can we specify what will appear in the client credit card statement?

To be more precise : when the client will check his card statement, he will see PAYPAL....
after the PAYPAL...: with the paypal.Buttons, can we choose what will be shown like the name of the product or invoice number?

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/

createSubscription or createOrder....

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=SB_CLIENT_ID&vault=true"> </script>
  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
paypal.Buttons({
  createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
    return actions.subscription.create({
      'plan_id': 'P-....'
    });
  },
  onApprove: function(data, actions) {
    alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID);
  }
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

If the client pays with a credit card or a bank account in his paypal account, is there a way to specify what will appear in the client credit card or bank statement?

Answer (score 1):

The argument passed to createOrder is a v2/checkout/orders creation object, which will have an array of purchase_units, documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-purchase_unit_request . It accepts a `soft_descriptor` parameter.

---

The Subscriptions API and createSubscription function do not have an equivalent parameter. The credit card statement name can be set at the account level via https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/info/edit

Comment: Is there a example of real world javascript? would it look like `createOrder: function(data, actions) {
     return actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
      amount: {
     value:5.00,
      },
      soft_descriptor:{
     value:'statement',
      },
    }]
     });
   },`

Comment: soft_descriptor is the key name of a string, not an object

Comment: ah ok, I see... so more like this `return actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
      amount: {
     value:'5.23',
      },
      soft_descriptor:'statement'
    }]
     });`